# Difference between list() and [ ] in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Is there any difference between `list()` and `[]` while initializing a `list` in Python 3?

Comment: To my knowledge they are equivalent.

Comment: Technically speaking, one is a function that returns an object casted to a list, and the other is the literal list object itself. Kinda like `int(0)` vs `0`. In practical terms there's no difference.

Comment: I'd expect `[]` to be faster, because it does not involve a global lookup followed by a function call. Other than that, it's the same.

Comment: Compare `list = int; list()` with `list = int; []`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `list()` is a *function that returns a* `list` *object* and `[]` is the *list object itself*, the second form is faster since it doesn't involve the function call:

```
> python3 -m timeit 'list()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0853 usec per loop

> python3 -m timeit '[]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0219 usec per loop
```

So if you really want to find a difference, there's that. In practical terms they're the same, however.

Comment: This is compilation level major difference. Thanks @jfaccioni. Upvoting this.

Comment: i added a timing example to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154343/4954037) where `list` is faster. i admit it is a special case...

Answer (score 4):

they are close to equivalent; the constructor variant does a function lookup and a function call; the literal does not - disassembling the python bytecode shows:

```
from dis import dis


def list_constructor():
    return list()

def list_literal():
    return []


print("constructor:")
dis(list_constructor)

print()

print("literal:")
dis(list_literal)
```

this outputs:

```
constructor:
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 RETURN_VALUE

literal:
  8           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

as for the timing: the benchmark given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154346/4954037) may be misleading for some  (probably rare) cases. compare e.g. with this:

```
$ python3 -m timeit 'list(range(7))'
1000000 loops, best of 5: 224 nsec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit '[i for i in range(7)]'
1000000 loops, best of 5: 352 nsec per loop
```

it seems that constructing a list from a generator is faster using `list` than a list-comprehension. i assume this is because the `for` loop in the list-comprehension is a python loop whereas the same loop is run in the `C` implementation in the python interpreter in the `list` version.

---

also note that `list` can be reassigned to something else (e.g. `list = int` now `list()` will just return the integer `0`) - but you can not tinker with `[]`.

and while it may be obvious... for completeness: the two versions have a different interface: [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) accepts exactls on iterable as argument. it will iterate over it and put the elements into the new list; the literal version does not (except for explicit list-comprehensions):

```
print([0, 1, 2])  # [0, 1, 2]
# print(list(0, 1,2))  # TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 3

tpl = (0, 1, 2)
print([tpl])           # [(0, 1, 2)]
print(list(tpl))       # [0, 1, 2]

print([range(3)])      # [range(0, 3)]
print(list(range(3)))  # [0, 1, 2]

# list-comprehension
print([i for i in range(3)])      # [0, 1, 2]
print(list(i for i in range(3)))  # [0, 1, 2]  simpler: list(range(3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Functionally they produce the same result, different internal Python implementation:

```
import dis


def brackets():
    return []


def list_builtin():
    return list()
```

```
print(dis.dis(brackets))
  5           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
print(dis.dis(list_builtin))
 9           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us take this example:

```
A = ("a","b","c")
B = list(A)
C = [A]

print("B=",B)
print("C=",C)

# list is mutable:
B.append("d")
C.append("d")

## New result
print("B=",B)
print("C=",C)

Result:
B= ['a', 'b', 'c']
C= [('a', 'b', 'c')]

B= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
C= [('a', 'b', 'c'), 'd']
```

Based on this example, we can say that: **[ ]** doesn't try to convert tuple into a list of elements  while **list()** is a method that try to convert  tuple into list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The [list()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/list_list.htm) method takes sequence types and converts them to lists. This is used to convert a given tuple into list.

```
sample_touple = ('a', 'C', 'J', 13)
list1 = list(sample_touple)
print ("List values ", list1)

string_value="sampletest"
list2 = list(string_value)
print ("List string values : ", list2)
```

Output :

```
List values  ['a', 'C', 'J', 13]                                                                                                                              
List string values :  ['s', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e', 't', 'e', 's', 't']
```

Where `[]` to direct declare as list

```
sample = [1,2,3]
```